# Meaning of "I'm a disaster"

Tags: nouns, idioms, meaning-in-context

What does *disaster* mean in the following sentence?

> I'm a disaster.

Comment: What is the context? You should post a longer passage of text in which this phrase occurs, lest you get no meaningful answer...

Comment: Meaning of [disaster](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/disaster?q=disaster#disaster__9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this dictionary entry at [Oxford:](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/disaster?q=disaster)

> disaster: 
> noun:
> a sudden accident or a natural catastrophe that causes great damage or loss of life:
> 159 people died in the disaster
> [mass noun]: informal a person or thing that is a complete failure:
> lunch had turned out to be a total disaster

So, it is generally (may change on context) used to say how messed up (or hopeless) as a person the speaker is.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, a person will say this if he/she

- is unkempt. Messy hair, dirty clothes, lack of personal hygiene, etc...
- is at a difficult emotional state. It can be caused by relationship troubles, unexpected life situations, or recent trauma.
- is performing poorly at a game or task. *"I cannot shoot any hoops tonight. I am a disaster."*

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the most important thing for understanding the words, their exact meaning, is to know their root - their *etymology*. In this particular case, the word *disaster* has its origin from Latin words *dis* which means *bad* and *aster* which means a *star*. Therefore *disaster* is a *bad star*! 
Our predecessors relied on astrology and they believed that the positions of stars can tell something about our life, about our destiny…

Comment: Etymology and other background material is good, but it's important to actually answer the question: What does it mean in context?